# Javascript - Using strings to construct an object properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have got about 100 *PC Specification* dropdowns like one of them is given below:

```
<select class="drpProcessor spec-gen" name="processor_id">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="23">Some Processor</option>               
</select>
```

What I want to achieve is an object of the whole specification (i.e. all the 100 spec dropdowns with their values in an object) like following:

```
var specs = {
    processor_id : 21,
    ram_id : 34,
    motherboard_id: 45,
    ...
    ...
};
```

I know that I can achieve this using something like the following:

```
var specs = {
    processor_id : $('.drpProcessor').val(),
    ram_id : $('.drpRam').val(),
    motherboard_id: $('.drpMotherBoard').val(),
    ...
    ...
};
```

But that would be a tedious job to do ( as I would have to write this for 100 dropdowns ). Fortunately, I have the name applied to each of the drop down that I would want to take as the respective spec's property. So I went on and wrote this little snippet that takes the name off of each of the drop down and tries to create this name a property of the `specs` object:

```
var els = $('#deassTab select');

// construct the specs object
var specs = {};
$(els).each(function( index, elem ){
   specs.($(elem).prop('name')) = $(elem).val(); // <-- Problem Lies here
})
```

But it doesn't allow me to do so and gives this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

The problem lies at `specs.($(elem).prop('name'))` i.e. where I am trying to add this property to the `specs` object via `string`. Is ther any way that I can achieve this i.e. create an object's property using string?

Comment: `specs[elem.name] = elem.value;` ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is the line:

```
specs.($(elem).prop(name)) = $(elem).val();
```

Where, when you want to use strings to dynamically set properties, you use square bracket syntax (and no dots) making that line:

```
specs[$(elem).prop(name)] = $(elem).val();
```

Which should resolve your problem.